# Paypal Donate Button not working

Tags: button, paypal, joomla2.5

I have just attempted to place a basic Paypal Donate button on my Joomla 2.5 website: 
http://zoo2u.co.uk/index.php/projects-zoo2u-support

However when you click on the link it doesn't go anywhere.

The code I've pasted into the Article is:

Answer (score 0):

It's because your rich text editor filters out javascript from what you entered.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is true, for a quick fix it would be best to use a plugin like Sourcer by No Number: https://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/sourcerer

Also 2.5 has been discontinued, it would be a good idea to update.